# Array or List of buttons in TCL

Tags: arrays, list, button, tcl

I'm a complete noob in TCL and I'm sure the question is really simple but because I was getting confused trying to find the answer, I decided to ask it here. So, sorry if the answer is really obvious!

I have 9 buttons manually created like this:

```
set fr1 [frame $ttt_w.fr1]

button $fr1.one -text "one" -background green
button $fr1.two -text "two" -background green
button $fr1.three -text "three" -background green
```

Now I want to add these 9 buttons into a 2D matrix, list or array and configure their properties in a for loop. For instance changing their background color. Therefore, it would be like `lst(1,1)` represents button one and `lst(1,1).background` allows me to alter it.

How may I go about achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use associative arrays to hold widget names.

```
set lst(1,1) [button $fr1.one -text "one" -background green]
set lst(1,2) [button $fr1.two -text "dos" -background green]
set lst(2,1) [button $fr1.three -text "drei" -background green]
set lst(2,2) [button $fr1.four -text "quattro" -background green]
```

Now let's arrange them:

```
foreach y {1 2} {
    foreach x {1 2} {
        # There's many ways to do this...
        grid $lst($x,$y) -x $x -y $y
    }
}
```

OK, now let's configure one of them

```
# The *old* classic Tk color from waaaaay back when...
$lst(2,1) configure -background bisque
```

Making `lst(2,1).background` work directly as written for configuring the background of the above *is* possible, but I really wouldn't advise it given that what I write above is available instead. Were you to insist on doing it, you'd do:

```
proc lst(2,1).background {{color "\u0000"}} {
    global lst
    if {$color eq "\u0000"} {
        # Illegal sentinel value, so we read instead
        return [$lst(2,1) cget -background]
    }
    $lst(2,1) configure -background $color
}
```

(That's right. That *is* a legal procedure name.) But this gets really rather ugly and takes a lot of effort to extend to everything and… well, don't do it, yes?

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot. I May have other questions later but this definitely helped a lot.